# how I can use http post flutter with django

Tags: python, django, api, flutter, django-rest-framework

I want to make it without Django REST Framework.

This is my code:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def index1(request):
    cursor.execute('select * from users where id = %s', [request.POST])
    response = list(cursor.fetchall())
    return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

and when I use flutter HTTP POST it gives me this

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /index1
[04/Jun/2021 00:20:25] "POST /index1 HTTP/1.1" 403 2870
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with django, but I think the error is clear. You need to provide a CSRF token (the according cookie). Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want to validate CSRF (generally only if this is an API)

```py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def index1(request):
    cursor.execute('select * from users where id = %s',[request.POST])
    response = list(cursor.fetchall())
    return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

See the documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt